# Nginx: set subdomain as part of 404 page address

Tags: nginx

I have a multi language site which have sub domains for every language. I want to use the sub domain as part the name of my custom static error page.

Example

```
 error_page  404 error/$subdomain.not_found.html
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just an example...

```
server {
    server_name ~^(?<subdomain>.+)\.yourmaindomain\.com$;
    # blablabla
    error_page  404 error/$subdomain.not_found.html;
}
```